# Advanced Encryption Standard

Tags: aes

I had done an example on AES-128 bit.But while doing AES-192 bit,i am facing below problem. 
what is the order of the matrix after mixed column step in 192 bit AES?

Answer (score 3):

> what is the order of the matrix after mixed column step in 192 bit AES?

The only differences between AES-128 and AES-192 are

- the key scheduling is different
- AES-192 has two more rounds.

There is no difference in any of the steps.

What you might be trying to look at is Rijndael with a 192 bit block size; there are differences in the shift row steps, which *might* be what you are looking at.  However, that has little to do with AES, which always has a 128 bit block size.

Comment: in mixed column step,Is state matrix is same for 128,192 bit??   i mean                    we use [02 03 01 01] as first row of state matrix in mixed column step..will it same for all AES types?

Comment: @ACP: that is correct, the mixed column step doesn't change based on key size

Comment: okay...then how we have to do XOR in next ADD ROUND KEY method?...the order of the two matrices will be 4*6 and 4*6...??

Comment: @ACP: no, the matrices are always 4*4.  Making the keys 192 modifies how the round keys are computed, not their size...

Comment: key length is 192 bit right?..i wrote it in 4*6 matrix form

Comment: @ACP: I don't care how you represent it yourself; that's not how AES works internally...

Comment: only 128 bit key is used for add round key method??

Comment: @ACP: each round key is 128 bits; for AES-192, there are 13 such round keys, and the 192 bit key is used to compute them

Comment: Can we use AES algorithm of 192 bit key size for plain text of 192 bit?

Comment: @ACP: AES has a block size of 128 bits, always.  However, with an appropriate mode of operation, you can encrypt plaintexts of any size.

Comment: okay..to encrypt 192 bit plain text,what will change in the AES operation??..I mean we have to write it in 4*6 matrix??

Comment: one more question..In mixed column step,how those state matrix values came??(02 03 01 01)

Comment: @ACP: where does 02 03 01 01 come from?  The AES designers picked those values...