# AES-192 bit fixed matrix values in mixed column step

Tags: encryption, aes

In advanced encryption standard,in mixed column step,how those fixed matrix values came? The values are `(02 03 01 01)`,
will these values will be the same for 192 bit plain text?

Comment: This was already answered on your previous question https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/53308/advanced-encryption-standard